# How to use react-router's Redirect Component to redirect to a dynamically generated route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

This is a simplified version of my route configuration. I am using react-router 2.4.0. Right now when I hit the root '/' it redirects me to 'parent-route':

```
 <Redirect from="/" to="parent-route" />
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <Route path="parent-route" >
         <IndexRoute component={SomeComponent1} />
         <Route path="child-route-1/:entityId" component={SomeComponent2} />
         <Route path="child-route-2/:entityId" component={SomeComponent3} />       
    </Route>
</Route>
```

But I want to change the behavior of `Redirect` to redirect to a child-route with a concrete Id set. To be more precise I want to do something like this

```
<Redirect from="/" to="parent-route/child-route-1/[firstAvailableEntityId]" />
```

I have the list of all available entities in the redux-store. Does anyone have an idea how to combine `Redirect` with `Redux-Store` to generate a dynamic redirect Url?

I tried to wrap the `Redirect` Component and connected it to the store. But this does not work cause the render-method of `Redirect` never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

```
import store from './yourStore.js'

function onIndexEnter (nextState, replace) {
    const state = store.getState()
    // put some logic here to decide your new id...
    replace(`/your-redirect-url/${newId}`
}

const routes = (<Redirect onEnter={onIndexEnter} from="/" to="parent-route" />
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <Route path="parent-route" >
         <IndexRoute component={SomeComponent1} />
         <Route path="child-route-1/:entityId" component={SomeComponent2} />
         <Route path="child-route-2/:entityId" component={SomeComponent3} />       
    </Route>
</Route>)
```

But I think it would be easier and cleaner not to use a Redirect in this case. Instead, you could put your redirection logic inside `componentWillMount` of your top level component, or in the onEnter hook of your top level route, where you can decide where to redirect in a dynamic way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will try an approach here without Redirect.